# Query to find out More than 1 instance of a value against particular column: Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in oracle with fol structure:-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
 student_id  | Subject_Name | Is_Additional  | Is_Major
---------------------------------------------------------------
   9001         Physics            Yes             Yes
   9001         Algebra            Yes             No
   9001         English            Yes             No
   9002         Physics            Yes             Yes (9002)
   9002         Algebra            Yes             Yes
   9004         Mathematics        Yes             Yes
   9005         English            Yes             Yes  (9005)
   9005         Algebra            Yes             Yes
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

A student can have more than one additional subjects but only one major is to be set to 'Yes' value. Now i want to find out all students where they have
selected more than one Major in case above 9002 and 9005.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use aggregation and `HAVING`

```
 select student_id
 from data
 where is_major = 'yes'
 group by student_id
 having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: sorry. this query did not return 9002 and 9005. indeed it did not return any row at all. pl redeem.

Answer (score 0):

Radim's answer will work for selecting `student_id`. If you need the whole row:

```
select student_id, subject_name
from (
    select *, count(*) over (partition by student_id) as major_count
    from data
    where is_major = 'yes'
) t;
```

Of course an alternative is also to incorporate Radim's answer via a subquery:

```
select * from data
where student_id in (
    select student_id
    from data
    where is_major = 'Yes'
    group by student_id
    having count(*) > 1
);
```

I believe those will produce different plans so you might want to try them both.

Comment: sorry. this query did not return 9002 and 9005. indeed it did not return any row at all. pl redeem.

Comment: That's probably because I didn't capitalize `'yes'`.

Comment: No. I took care of that earlier. Issue is in query logic. i even trimmed is_major field to compare it to 'Yes' but it did not return the desired two rows which are 9002 and 9005

Comment: Is `is_major' strictly yes/no or does include all that extra stuff in parentheses?

Comment: sir is either 'Yes' or 'No' the brackets 'stuff' was for reference